how to handle validate form to next page use vue router
a form after validate must go to next author page with vue-Router using this code but not validate
  <form @submit.prevent="handlesubmit">

            <div class="row">
              

                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="" v-model.lazy.trim="form.nameTitle">
                    <div class=" text-danger">
                        {{ form.titleNameErrorText }}
                    </div>
                </div>
               

            <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-6 ">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-style" type="submit" >Submit
                        </button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>

js code and vue router handle next page after validation

> import { reactive } from "vue";
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router'

export default {
    setup() {
        const router = useRouter();
        const form = reactive({
            nameTitle: "",
            familyTitle: "",
            addressTitle: "",
            phoneNumber: "",
            titleNameErrorText: "",
            titleFamilyErrorText: "",
            titleAddressErrorText: "",
            titlePhoneErrorText: "",
            name: "FormAddress",

        });



        function validate() {


            if (form.nameTitle.length < 3) {
                form.titleNameErrorText = "نام حداقل باید دارای 3 حرف باشد   "
            }
            else {
                form.titleNameErrorText = ""
            }
            if (form.familyTitle.length < 3) {
                form.titleFamilyErrorText = "نام خانوادگی حداقل باید دارای 3 حرف باشد   "
            }

            else {
                form.titleFamilyErrorText = ""
            }
            if (form.addressTitle.length < 3) {
                form.titleAddressErrorText = "آدرس حداقل باید دارای 3 حرف باشد   "
            }

            else {
                form.titleAddressErrorText = ""
            }

            const phonepattern = /^09\d{9}$/;
            if (!phonepattern.test(form.phoneNumber)) {
                form.titlePhoneErrorText = "شماره وارد شده صحیح نمی باشد"
            }
            else {
                form.titlePhoneErrorText = "";
            }


        }


        function handlesubmit() {

            if (validate()) {
                console.log("amir")
                router.push({ name: 'map' })
            }

        }

        return { form, validate, handlesubmit }



    },



}




submit go to map page and no validate this current page im handle validate page and success form element next page else stay this page
///////////////////

if (validate()) you need to make the function validate return true if validation passed, and false if it did not,  for this line to work.
